# Fragment implements OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I've got an application that I'm modernizing. One step of this process is changing to a Fragment based layout (using the Fragments from the support library).
I converted my Activities into Fragments, and got the layout working nicely (using a ViewPager, cool stuff!)

I was having my Activities implement OnClickListener for all of my button-pressing needs. I have the new Fragment incarnations doing the same thing of course, but it looks like "onClick" is never getting hit. Is there something special about Fragments that prevents them from working this way?

Comment: I assume you mean it's implementing it? As in, `public class YourFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener`? If so, can you show us how you attach the listener as well as the `onClick` method?

Comment: Are you findByViewId in the onCreateView method and then attaching the listener in the onActivityCreated method?

Comment: Oops, wow, I'm a little overtired. Yes, I meant implementing, sorry. And I'm findViewByIding and attaching the listener in the Update() method. Speaking of which, is that actually even a thing? I don't even have an onActivityCreated method. Hmm

Comment: Check if your `Update()` method is getting called. If it's not, implement [`onViewCreated(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) and call it from there.

Comment: That fixed it! I wish I could give you the "accept". I have no idea what I was doing (clearly I _had_ no idea what I was doing)

Answer (score 47):

Just do one this

```
public class fragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button myButton;

    @Override
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        myButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // implements your things
    }
}
```

very simple

Comment: Simple things are the most extraordinary. But only the wise are able to see it. Thanks a lot. Was trying to figure it for many hours.

Comment: I forgot:
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
Oh men @@! Wasted my time after long time come back with android. Thanks.

Comment: That saved my day, Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

> I will Focus to use the OnClick action for global access, You have to do like this is your project, Must Implement the **View.OnClickListener**, then Override the Method
> **OnClick()**, In **OnCreateView()** have to do like this **button_submit.setOnClickListener(this);** for the Views you need,
> Please see the below code for Clear Answer,Thankyou.

```
public class New_Project extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
private View mView;
private Button button_submit;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newproject, container,false);
    button_submit=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
    button_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_submit:
            //do your stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I want to comment on Abhijit Chakra answer but it seems that I need to have 50 reps for that. For those who are wondering if you can't use Abhijit's answer, it is because of:

```
public void OnClick(View v) {
    // implements your things
}
```

You need to make sure that it is onClick, NOT OnClick. Thankfully Android Studio internal error message come to rescue.

Answer (score 2):

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.imgView1:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateImage();
        break;
      case R.id.imgView2:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateImage();
        break;
      case R.id.imgView3:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateImage();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
```