# Nested fragments: Detect click on outer fragment from within inner fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My application has two nested fragments like in the picture below:

[image: Fragments]

How is it possible to detect clicks on `Fragment1` from within the instance of `Fragment2`?

Comment: Please include some more information in your question like the layout XML or any approaches you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the cuff, I would say to create a listener `interface` in `Fragment1`, then implement that interface in `Fragment2` and call the appropriate method in the interface in `Fragment1`'s `onClick` method.

## Edit

This is a pretty barebones example, and I haven't tested it, but here's the general theory. Of course, you'll need to add in your logic and fill in necessary methods like `onCreate`.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize your activity here

        Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        // Give fragment1 a reference to fragment2
        fragment1.registerListener(fragment2);
        // Do your fragment transactions here
    }
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    // This is the interface. You can put as many abstract methods here as you want
    // with whatever parameters you want, but they all have to be overriden
    // in fragment2
    public interface FragmentClickListener {
        void onFragmentClick();
    }

    FragmentClickListener mListener;

    // This fragment needs to have a reference to the other fragment
    // This method can take any class that implements FragmentClickListener
    public void registerListener(FragmentClickListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // You must check to make sure something is listening before you use the interface
        if (mListener != null) {
            //Let the interface know this fragment was clicked
            mListener.onFragmentClick();
        }
    }

}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment implements FragmentClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onFragmentClick() {
        // Do whatever you want to do when fragment1 is clicked
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't include it because I initially assumed you already knew this part, but you would also need to register the fragment as clickable. I've only ever used OnClickListener on buttons, which can be made clickable through xml, but here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14951225/1541763

Comment: Hey thanks. I will try to implement this as soon as possible. :)